# Perl: Is there a DBI function similar to statistics_info, to retrieve FK references and constraints?

Tags: perl, postgresql, foreign-keys, dbi, dbd-pg

When performing a `\d+` on a table within Postgres, it lists the table schema along with the indexes, as well as other tables that reference it as a FK.  Example:

```
    Table "public.foo_table"
   Column   | Type |   Modifiers   | Storage  | Description 
------------+------+---------------+----------+-------------
 id         | text |               | extended | 
 foo        | text |               | extended | 
 bar        | text |               | extended | 
Indexes:
    "foo_table_id_idx" btree (id)
    "foo_table_foobar_idx" btree (foo,bar)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "foo_table_bar_fk" FOREIGN KEY (bar) REFERENCES public.bar_table(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "public.bar_table" CONSTRAINT "bar_table_foo_fk" FOREIGN KEY (foo) REFERENCES public.foo_table(foo)
Has OIDs: no
```

---

You can do something `$dbh->statistics_info(...)` to retrieve the index information.  Is there something similar to retrieve the FK info (references and referenced-by)?

---

*It seems like my next option is to either issue a `->do()` command, or query the system tables.*

Comment: found `foreign_key_info`, I'll check to see how its used, since it takes 6 arguments (odd)

Comment: Self-learner badge on go for @vol7ron :)

Comment: @stackoverflow: I really wish you didn't delete your answer, I really do think it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What I've found so far:

```
$dbh->foreign_key_info( pk_cat, pk_schema, pk_tbl
                      , fk_cat, fk_schema, fk_tbl      );

# FK References
$dbh->foreign_key_info( undef , undef    , undef   
                      , undef , undef    , $table_name );

# FK Referenced By
$dbh->foreign_key_info( undef , undef    , $table_name 
                      , undef , undef    , undef       );

## Putting the schema/catalog info only ensures you are hitting the intended 
##    table. If you have dupicate tables, or your table is not in the public 
##    schema it's probably a good idea to include the schema.
## Catalog is generally unnecessary for Postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run psql with the `-E` option it will show all the queries it runs to respond to `\d` (and other) metadata requests.  It's pretty easy to copy/paste from that to get the queries you want.

Comment: That could be a good alternative.  I do have queries already to retrieve the info, I was looking for something a little cleaner, though